# PHP Garbage collection when nullifying

Tags: php, garbage-collection

If I were to do this:

```
$bob = new Bob();

function AnnoyBob( Bob $bob )
{
    $bob = NULL;
} // < A 

AnnoyBob( $bob );
```

**A:** Does `$bob` now lose its reference to the original pointer and now point to `NULL` thus having to get collected on the next GC?

```
$bob = new Bob();

function AnnoyBob( Bob $bob )
{
    unset( $bob );
} // < B    

AnnoyBob( $bob );
```

**B:** Is the `$bob` pointer now instantly releasing the memory for overwriting?

**C:** What if you were to pass in the reference here instead: `..( Bob &$bob )`

[image]

My point being, I see people nullifying pointers not realising that they are now leaving GC to do their dirty work... whereas if you use unset, I am wondering if it explicitly marks it to be available for overwriting then and there (deleted)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only ever modify the variable inside the function. Your `Bob` instance will continue to exist, because variables outside the function are still referencing it. Bob won't get garbage collected until *all* references to it are gone/have become inaccessible.

An object instance exists somewhere in a pool of object instances in memory. A variable "holding an object" actually just holds an identifier of that object in memory. If you unset or overwrite that reference, the object itself is not altered. When passing it into a function, you're just passing a copy of the identifier into the function; then see previous sentence.

If you're passing it by reference, then you can modify the caller's variable's content. If you just `unset` this variable, it will just unset it inside the function, so nothing much happens to Bob. Only if you pass it by reference and you reassign another value to that variable will Bob get garbage collected.

I.e., only in this scenario are you overwriting the last object reference and cause it to become garbage collected:

```
$bob = new Bob();

function AnnoyBob(Bob &$bob) {
    $bob = NULL;
}

AnnoyBob($bob);
```

Comment: I've added to my OP, My question was most likely a request for vindication on not nullifying pointers... rather unsetting them. I guess from your last part I am indeed right.

Comment: Only thing I'd add to this, assuming I'm remembering correctly, is that PHP garbage collects "dead" variables at function closure - so there's not much point in unsetting `$bob` inside the function just before you close it.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 in PHP `unset($var)` and `$var = null` are pretty much synonymous - you can check this by doing `echo is_null($var) ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL";` after running `unset($var)` (or, indeed, without setting `$var` in the first place) - in either case it'll echo out *NULL* - any variable that hasn't been set is null.

Comment: @Jimmy PHP *never* "deletes then and there". Even if you `unset`, you're merely unsetting the symbol table entry that points to the value. The value and memory itself will get garbage collected eventually. There's very little point in worrying about such details of memory consumption in PHP. The only thing you can do is to be careful not to use too much memory through inefficient algorithms or by outright storing too much data "in variables". Beyond that PHP handles memory for you, period.

Comment: Unless it's a reference that you wanted to get rid of right? Otherwise your $bob pointer is still pointing to the Bob memory

Comment: @deceze.... If you are looping through data from an API and each loop you don't need that bit of data any more as you've already created it in your database and wanna forget about it (or a pointer to it)... you bet your ass you're going to want to remove it from your memory... so I was wondering if there is a way of actually deleting it then and there! ... but the comments here are valuable and helpful... thank you!

Comment: @CD001 A non-existent variable will will cause warnings to be emitted, and its value will be substituted by `null`; however a set variable holding the value `null` is a perfectly legitimate variable with a value. There *are* differences.

Comment: @Jimmy Sure, overwrite that variable if you don't need it anymore. But again: this will not immediately free memory! It will merely mark the memory as recoverable, which will happen sometime later as necessary.

Comment: @deceze - good point; makes no practical difference if you're checking with `!empty($var)` but yeah, you're right - it's not quite synonymous.

Comment: @CD0 I've written about that extensively... :) [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: So what we're saying is, there's simply no way of removing memory when you don't need it??? This can't be true <cries>... Re-assigning a pointer to a new bit of memory does not mean the memory is now available for writing... It has to wait for GC to pick up on it... surely that's wrong?

Comment: @Jimmy That's what I'm saying. PHP does not give you *any* programmatic access to **memory**. At all. It isolates you entirely from it. PHP doesn't have anything resembling C pointers. The only thing you can do is to *force* gc to run. But PHP will run gc *as needed*, i.e. when you're approaching the memory limit or every so often for long running programs.

Comment: @Jimmy You're welcome. Worrying about memory (beyond generalities) is a waste of time in PHP. Unsetting or nullifying variables doesn't really do anything for the most part. You should write a lot of short self-contained functions through which variables go out of scope quickly automatically; that's the best memory control you can do because it's implicit, you don't need to waste a lot of code on it and it makes your code better overall.

Comment: Just as a side note.. I have a process that contains 500mb of memory and iterates over it... From this conversation I am now going to force a garbage collection at the end of the scope as it's memory I want to reclaim as soon as possible... I however wouldn't dream of doing this for everything do to the performance hit. `gc_collect_cycles `